# Can someone please help me translate this chop/seal/stamp?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, character-identification

Back in 1994 my mother and I took a trip to Hong Kong to visit my grandfather, a US ex-pat, that lived there. She had this chop commissioned while we were visiting.

Unfortunately, I don't have any way to determine what she had asked to be engraved, as she had a stroke about 8 years ago and cannot remember the stamp. All I know is that it is soapstone and I thought it would be her name "Lynne" or her family name "Curran" or the combination "Lynne Curran".

When I searched for her name "Lynne", I found 琳恩. The first symbol, or part of it, **琳** 恩 seems to be incorporated into the chop.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

[image]

Comment: It's 莉 (lì), which corresponds to the "Ly" part.

Comment: When we wanted name our daughter, my wife decided her English/local name as Jasmine Amanda, naturally, I name her 茉莉 as her Chinese name.  Maybe your mother had a Chinese name not related to Lynne at all as "meaningful" is always the priority for Chinese names.  Maybe you can search your mother's things:  there might be a piece of paper with her Chinese name written and explaining the meaning as I understand this is a practice for Hong Kong seal carver to foreigners.

Comment: These 2 silks are very old. My Grandpa brought them back from Japan in the 40’s (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn1EH.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaIEX.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWUAj.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

the character is 莉 (u+8389), [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/lei6.Mp3); it’s the transliteration of “lynne”.

“莉” originally means grass (艸); later used for white jasmine as in “茉莉”.

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=莉](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%8E%89)

imo, it’s quite good, for female name